# ApplicationPoolIdentity 503 Error

Tags: http, iis, webserver, application-pool

This morning I have tried to load all my websites on my local PC that has IIS 7.5  and straight away i get a HTTP 503 Error.

HTTPerr log says: 2012-08-17 08:43:26 127.0.0.1 49326 127.0.0.1 80 HTTP/1.1 GET / 503 3 AppOffline web80

So my application pool is not starting. I try restarting the app pool in IIS and I still get the error. When I look at the App pool I see that it has stopped. So I look in Event viewer:

Error: WAS : Application pool 'web80' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Warning: WAS : The Windows Process Activation Service failed to create a worker process for the application pool 'web80'. The data field contains the error number.

Looking around the web and stackoverflow, the problem seems to be caused by app pools identity being apppoolidentity. I changed this to local system and it works.

But why out the blue would this just stop working? I've read another solution that you need to provide permission to

C:\Windows\System32\config\Schema but I don't have a Schema folder.Could that be the reason why?

Really all I want to know is how do I get the application pool to reuse the apppoolidentity or where can I look to try things out? I could try re-intall iis but if I can figure out what causes this, I might be able to prevent it in the future.

Thanks

Comment: Is your AppPoolIdentity user in the IIS_USRS group?

Comment: Yeah it is in the IIS_USRS group

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this recently. In my scenario, I had the Application Pool Identity set to my Active Directory account under the 'Custom account' setting. Recently I updated my password so I just reset my password for the 'Custom account' accordingly and I was able to reload my application.
[image: App pool settings - Setting Identtiy with 'Custom account']